# Ejabberd - Getting current users number for a specific cluster node

Tags: erlang, cluster-computing, ejabberd

I have a cluster running multiple nodes on different machines and would like to create different graphs showing the current number of users connected per machine.

Running ejabberdctl connected_users_number on any of the machines returns the sum of connected users to all cluster nodes.

Is it possible to get the number of users currently connected only to specific specific machine/node?

Answer (score 0):

There are commands in stats and session that maybe return only local (not cluster) information, see and try:

```
 ejabberdctl help --tags
```

On the other hand, you can obtain that information directly from the operating system:

```
 $ netstat | grep xmpp-client
 tcp6       0      0 localhost:xmpp-client   localhost:39401         ESTABLISHED
```

Or more precisely:

```
 $ netstat | grep xmpp-client | wc -l
 1
```

The problem is that you would have to run this also for the BOSH port, or any other that you may allow clients to use to connect to your server...